# When comparing a variable to a literal, should one place the literal on the left or right of the equals '==' operator?

Tags: coding-style

When learning to code, I was taught the following style when checking the value of a variable:

```
int x;
Object *object;
...
if(x == 7) { ... }
if(object == NULL) { ... }
```

However, now that I am in the field, I have encountered more than one co-worker who swears by the approach of switching the lhs and rhs in the `if` statements:

```
if(7 == x) { ... }
if(NULL == object) { ... }
```

The reasoning being that if you accidentally type `=` instead of `==`, then the code will fail at compile.  Being unaccustomed to this style, reading `7 == x` is difficult for me, slowing my comprehension of their code.

It seems if I adopt this style, I will likely someday in the future save myself from debugging an `x = 7` bug, but in the mean time, every time somebody reads my code I may be wasting their time because I fear the syntax is unorthodox.

Is the `7 == x` style generally accepted and readable in the industry, or is this just a personal preference of my coworkers?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: It's really not. It depends on the language.

Comment: @JonSkeet Right. I assumed the OP programmed in a language where you can assign within conditionals, otherwise, what would the point be? My reasoning was that any construct weird enough to get a name (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html ) and whose superiority is yet doubtful enough that it needs a name must have enough arguments for and against that's it's a matter of taste which arguments you choose to ignore.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Even within a language, it will depend on what compiler you're using - basically whether you can mitigate the sole downside of the more natural way of expressing conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reasoning being that if you accidentally type = instead of ==, then the code will fail at compile.

True. On the other hand, I believe *modern* C and C++ compilers (I'm assuming you're using one of those languages? You haven't said) will warn you if you do this.

Have you tried it with the compiler you're using? If it doesn't do it by default, look to see if there are flags you can use to provoke it - ideally to make it an *error* rather than just a warning.

For example, using the Microsoft C compiler, I get:

```
cl /Wall Test.c
test.c(3) : warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression
```

That's pretty clear, IMO. (The *default* warning settings don't spot it, admittedly.)

> Being unaccustomed to this style, reading 7 == x is difficult for me, slowing my comprehension of their code.

Indeed. Your approach is the more natural style, and should (IMO) be used unless you're *really* dealing with a compiler which doesn't spot this as a potential problem (and you have no alternative to using that compiler).

EDIT: Note that this isn't a problem in all languages - not even all C-like languages.

For example, although both Java and C# have a similar `if` construct, the condition expression in both needs to be implicitly convertible to a Boolean value. While the assignment part would compile, the type of the expression in your first example would be `int`, which isn't implicitly convertible to the relevant Boolean type in either language, leading to a compile-time error. The rare situation where you'd still have a problem would be:

```
if (foo == true)
```

which, if typo'd to:

```
if (foo = true)
```

would compile and do the wrong thing. The MS C# compiler even warns you about that, although it's generally better to just use

```
if (foo)
```

or

```
if (!foo)
```

where possible. That just leaves things like:

```
if (x == MethodReturningBool())
```

vs

```
if (MethodReturningBool() == x)
```

which is still pretty rare, and there's still a warning for it in the MS C# compiler (and probably in some Java compilers).

Comment: Yes, I am using C++, but I intentionally left the question ambiguous, because I wasn't sure the problem and answer were language specific.

Comment: @CoryKlein: The problem *is* language specific. I'll edit that into my answer.